# Increment stat exponentially from initial value to final value in n levels

Tags: mathematics, game-design

Sorry if the title is not well explained. I'll try to explain as good as possible.

I have a stat with an initial value of 10 and need to increase that stat 50 times until it reaches 5000.

The formula for that is: stat = stat + ((5000 - 10) / 50). But this increases the number by the same amount every step, and I want to increase the number exponentially.

Anyone knows the formula for that?

Comment: [I answered an equivalent question about dividing a total XP count between levels with an exponential curve](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198166/39518) - check that out and see if you can use the same math for your case. If you run into trouble, edit your question to clarify where you need help with it.

Comment: What is the base of your exponent? or is that your question bound by 50 steps?

Comment: Since we haven't heard any reply from you, I'm assuming the link to the previous question was enough to solve your problem. I'm putting this question on hold as a duplicate of that one. If you still need help, **edit this question** to show how you've tried applying the earlier answer and where you've gotten stuck or need assistance, then we can re-open the question for new answers.